# Modular cycles?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, modular-forms

It is well known that cocycles (differential forms) and cycles share many properties through duality (e.g., de Rham). I've been reading about modular forms recently and I came with a very naive expectation: ***It should make sense to talk about modular cycles too.*** However, when I skim the literature, I find nothing on such objects...

Let me clarify a bit more what I mean.

Let $\tau\in\mathbb{H}$ and let $f(\tau)$ be a holomorphic function in $\mathbb{H}\cup \{i\infty\}$. Then we can look for functions $f(\tau)$ that transform under a modular transformation in a certain way. Ultimately, this leads us to the well-known concept of **modular forms** of weight $k$, satisfying the following transformation law $$f\left(\tau\right)d\tau\to(c\tau+d)^{k-2}f(\tau)d\tau,$$ under $\tau\to\frac{a\tau+b}{c\tau+d}$, where $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\in\text{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$.

What I am wondering about is if there exists in a dual version of such a criterion for cycles, which would lead to a well-define notion of **modular cycles**. I expect such a criterion to exist naively due to de Rham duality.

Any guidance to some literature would be very appreciated!

**Disclaimer:** I am a physicist, so this is not my field of expertise and I may ask something totally trivial or something that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I'm insufficiently expert to say anything substantive about this, but if no one gives a useful answer here you could google "modular periods". Also, the phrase "cycles" does get used in this context, as in work of Kudla and Rapoport ... maybe partly called "cycle conjectures", or something similar.

Comment: There is ample literature on this once you realize that you are talking about cohomology and homology with twisted coefficients.

Comment: Any particular suggestions that would help me to get your point?

Comment: For weight $k=2$ there is [Cremona](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/J.E.Cremona/book/fulltext/index.html). For $k\ne 2$ there are the [period polynomials of modular forms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.5802.pdf). They allow for find the first few coefficients of the eigenforms from homology stuff.